# How to turn off syntax auto correct in Spyder IDE?

Tags: python, autocomplete, spyder

I'm new to Python as well as using the Spyder IDE. When I was writing example codes and learning about for loops, I had noticed that I had forgotten to put the colon after for loop and Spyder corrected it for me automatically when I pressed enter to go to the next line.
I want to turn off this behavior. However, I do not want to turn off auto-predict.
I want to turn it off since I want to learn the syntax properly and not be ignorant of the correct way of writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To turn off the automatic insertion of colons after `for` loops, please go to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > Editor > Source code`

and deactivate the option called

`Automatic insertion of colons after 'for', 'if', 'def', etc`.

*Note*: There you can also disable other options that provide Python auto-correction features, as you can see below

[image: Spyder auto-correction preferences]

Comment: I recently joined github and recognized you from there. I was trying to update spyder to 5.1 version through the anaconda navigator but I guess it might take a month to be available on it. There’s also a bug where the icons overlap the text in the menu bar in 5.0 version but I think that’s already posted as an issue on github.

Comment: Yeah, that bug is already fixed but Anaconda hasn't updated Spyder to a more recent version. I hope they will do it soon.